# How to output images as figure/figcaption

Tags: images, media-library, html5

I'm trying to figure out how to output the WP images from the media uploader as Figure/Figcaption. Using the WP Twenty Sixteen theme the output is figure/figurecaption by default, and searching for the code I can't find how it's done. I thought that adding:

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'search-form',
        'comment-form',
        'comment-list',
        'gallery',
        'caption',
    ) );
```

Was enough. BTW, I want to clarify how they do it or what is the proper way to make it work. I've found snippets like this from ([here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/insert-images-within-figure-element-from-media-uploader/)):

```
function html5_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url) {
  $html5 = "<figure id='post-$id media-$id' class='align-$align'>";
  $html5 .= "<img src='$url' alt='$title' />";
  if ($caption) {
    $html5 .= "<figcaption>$caption</figcaption>";
  }
  $html5 .= "</figure>";
  return $html5;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

But in the Twenty Sixteen theme code I haven't found nothing similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'gallery' ) );` or with another arguments such as `search-form`, `comment-form`, `comment-list` and `caption`, its call as [Theme Markup](https://codex.wordpress.org/Semantic_Markup)

Added `gallery` and `caption` support was introduced since WordPress version 3.9.

> As of version 3.9 WordPress uses `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements,
>   instead of the generic definition list markup to output galleries. More on this in the [Make WordPress Core article](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/15/html5-galleries-captions-in-wordpress-3-9/). ~ WordPress

`add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'image_add_caption', 20, 8 );` was **default filter** in WordPress ( see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L441 ), thats why you can find it out in theme. With function [`image_add_caption`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_add_caption/), it will add shortcode `[caption]` in image.

Comment: Then, if I'm using the las wp version and have added html5 support, why the images does not output as figure/figcaption

Comment: For single image, you need to add text in Caption input field after you upload an image, then insert into editor, it will add shortcode caption for your image.

Comment: Thank you @Jevuska, it solved the problem. But, I think that even without caption the image element should be surrounded by the <figure> tag.

Comment: @Kevin I see, I think you sould add caption shortcode, it is a better approach to add element figcaption into selected image inside post content to display in front-end. If without shortcode as marker, and you need fire by function to add those elements into image in front-end, you will get many trouble which image that should use those elements. I hope you understand.